How to transfer colors from blender to game engines?
Is the color reproduction in blender realistic? I want to transfer color palettes from blender to unreal engine and Godot Engine. How can I do it? That the color reproduction would be as natural and realistic as possible. Hypothetically, so that the scene can be compared to what you can see on a summer day in Europe, the same colors.
